# dom4j maven missing artifact

Tags: maven, pom.xml, dom4j, artifact

I'm having a problem with dom4j in pom.xml.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.dom4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>dom4j-1.4</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

is annotated with "Missing artifact org.dom4j:dom4j-1.4:jar:1.4". Here's the pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.netline.edu</groupId>
<artifactId>EduRulesChange</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>EduRulesChange</name>

<properties>
    <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.portlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>portlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-jcl</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
        <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
        <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.4</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.portal</groupId>
        <artifactId>base-wp.base</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.portal</groupId>
        <artifactId>user-wp.user.api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.db2</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcc.DB2Driver</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.silvermedia.oswiata.lib</groupId>
        <artifactId>PortalMenu</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.dom4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>dom4j-1.4</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies> 

<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <configuration>


                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>

            </configuration>

        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                        <silent>true</silent>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                <version>6.0</version>
                                <type>jar</type>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself.-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>
                                        org.apache.maven.plugins
                                    </groupId>
                                    <artifactId>
                                        maven-dependency-plugin
                                    </artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>
                                        [2.1,)
                                    </versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>copy</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore></ignore>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>

<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <findbugsXmlOutput>true</findbugsXmlOutput>
                <findbugsXmlWithMessages>true</findbugsXmlWithMessages>
                <xmlOutput>true</xmlOutput>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jxr-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.10</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

When I replace the dom4j dependency with

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I'm getting the same error, but in the first line

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
```

Can you help?

Comment: Make sure you are able to access internet, the GAV co-ordinates look proper http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cdom4j%7Cdom4j%7C1.6.1%7Cjar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First remove your existing jar file from your .m2 folder, again run the maven install. Then your problem will solve.

Comment: This thing is not possible to every time. If any other solution is there?

Answer (score 1):

Since the version **2.0.x**, this library was changed to a different **groupId**. Instead of **dom4j**, it is now **org.dom4j** (see the image below). You can try to migrate it or just use a version before, like **1.6.1** (*but I really encourage you to use the new versions, given the security vulnerabilities in this old version*).

Your dependency settings should look like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.dom4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.4</version>
</dependency>
```